# Counta + Filter function on Google spreadsheet cannot give me a Zero

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use FILTER and COUNTA in Google spreadsheet.
[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXyUu.png)

The formula in E1 is =COUNTA(filter($A$1:$A$12,$A$1:$A$12>=$C1,$A$1:$A$12<=$D1))

This formula help me to filter and count the date (Column A) which is within the date range (Column C and D).

The result in E1 and E2 is correct. However, E3, E4, E5 do not give me a zero, as there is no date fit in the range.

Anyone can help me on this to make it return a Zero if there is no date fit in the date range?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Martin. The function COUNTA is designed to count ALL values in a dataset, including repeats, zero-length strings, whitespace, and even "#N/A"s. So, you must wrap your FILTER formula in IFERROR, thus resulting in a truly *empty* cell where there is no date range match.

```
=COUNTA( IFERROR( filter($A$1:$A$12,$A$1:$A$12>=$C1,$A$1:$A$12<=$D1)))
```

You can read more in the Google Sheets documentation on [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en).

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also you can go with:
`=COUNTA( IFNA( filter($A$1:$A$12,$A$1:$A$12>=$C1,$A$1:$A$12<=$D1)))`
Please make sure you **don't pass** the optional 2nd argument to IFNA function.